# How to initialize model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have :

```
  public class MainMenuModel
    {
        public string TransKey { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayUrl { get; set; }

        public string NumberOfMenu { get; set; }
        public bool hasSubMenu { get; set; }

        public SubMenuModel SubMenu { get; set; }

    }
```

and i have :

```
 public class SubMenuModel
    {
        public string TransKey { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfMenu { get; set; }

    }
```

How can i initialize  this submenu model in main menu model?

I start with this but i cant get property of submenu model

```
   MainMenu.Add(new MainMenuModel() { TransKey = "PROMOTIONS", StateName = "", DisplayUrl = "", NumberOfMenu = "6.", hasSubMenu = true });
```

Comment: "i cant get property" Please expand to either the compiler error or what you mean.

Comment: i see property but i dont know how to initialize them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can i initialize this submenu model in main menu model as follows. Initialized below all the properties of MainMenuModel as well as SubMenuModel with dummy values.

```
        var mainMenuInstance = new MainMenuModel
        {
            DisplayUrl = "DisplayUrl",
            hasSubMenu = true,
            NumberOfMenu = "1",
            StateName = "StateName",
            TransKey = "TransKey",

            SubMenu = new SubMenuModel
            {
                NumberOfMenu = 4,
                StateName = "StateName",
                TransKey = "TransKey"
            },

            // If you have list of sub menus, initialize like this
            SubMenuList = new List<SubMenuModel>() { 
                new SubMenuModel { NumberOfMenu = 1, StateName = "StateName", TransKey = "TransKey" },
                new SubMenuModel { NumberOfMenu = 2, StateName = "StateName", TransKey = "TransKey" } }
        };
```

Comment: what if its  public List< SubMenuModel> SubMenu { get; set; } how can i initialize then?

Comment: @None it is a list - `SubMenuList = new List<SubMenuModel>() { new SubMenuModel { NumberOfMenu = 1, StateName = "", TransKey = "" } }`